# Nim и SDL2 - проблема с типом Rect

Tags: sdl, sdl2

Есть следующий код на Nim с использованием официального libsdl2 [враппера](https://github.com/nim-lang/sdl2)

```
import sdl2

discard sdl2.init(INIT_EVERYTHING)

let
  window = createWindow("Tic-Tac-Toe", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 600, 390, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN)
  renderer = createRenderer(window, -1, Renderer_Accelerated or Renderer_PresentVsync or Renderer_TargetTexture)

proc loadImage(file: string): TexturePtr =
  let loadedImage = loadBMP(file)
  let texture = createTextureFromSurface(renderer, loadedImage)
  freeSurface(loadedImage)
  return texture

proc applySurface(x: cint, y: cint, tex: TexturePtr, rend: RendererPtr) =
  var pos: Rect
  pos.x = x
  pos.y = y
  queryTexture(tex, nil, nil, pos.w, pos.h)
  copy(rend, tex, nil, pos)

let
  background = loadImage("resources/bg.bmp")

clear(renderer)
applySurface(0, 0, background, renderer)
present(renderer)

var
  evt = sdl2.defaultEvent
  runGame = true

while runGame:
  while pollEvent(evt):
    if evt.kind == QuitEvent:
      runGame = false
      break

destroy window
```

При компиляции выдает следующую ошибку:

```
source.nim(19, 15) Error: type mismatch: got (TexturePtr, nil, nil, cint, cint)
but expected one of: 
sdl2.queryTexture(texture: TexturePtr, format: ptr uint32, access: ptr cint, w: ptr cint, h: ptr cint)
```

И аналогичную для 20 строки:

```
source.nim(20, 7) Error: type mismatch: got (RendererPtr, TexturePtr, nil, Rect)
but expected one of: 
system.copy(s: string, first: int)
system.copy(s: string, first: int, last: int)
sdl2.copy(renderer: RendererPtr, texture: TexturePtr, srcrect: ptr Rect, dstrect: ptr Rect)
```

При этом если, к примеру, передать nil дважды в copy(), всё в порядке. Прошу помочь разобраться с проблемой.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо за [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30822792/5006566) [bluenote10](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1804173/bluenote10). Перевод:

Ваша проблема в том, что процедуры, на которых срабатывает ошибка, требуют `ptr` (указатели) на соответствующие типы данных, не сами данные. Например, требуется `ptr cint`, но вы передаете явный `cint`. Вам нужно взять `addr` (адрес) `cint` чтобы получить `ptr cint`. Например:

```
var w = pos.w
var h = pos.h
queryTexture(tex, nil, nil, w.addr, h.addr)
```

Обратите внимание, что для того, чтобы "взять адрес", вам нужна переменная `var` типа (подробнее смотрите в [этом вопросе](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30132599/1804173)). Поскольку `pos` - `var`, `pos.w.addr` и `pos.h.addr` тоже сработает. Аналогично вам нужно использовать `pos.addr` в качестве последнего параметра `copy`.

Comment: Во-первых, лучше приводить ссылку на ответ, а не на профиль автора ответа. Во-вторых, это русскоязычный ресурс - если хотите написать ответ, то напишите его в переводе, на русском языке. Возможно, что это сможет помочь ещё кому-то, кто столкнётся с аналогичной проблемой.

Comment: Спасибо за замечание, исправил.